# java Encryption performance

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a huge .txt file, The problem is the decryption is very slow, I tried AES,DES,3DES,BlowFish algorithms with different modes but the decryption still slow

here is my code :

```
static
{
    try
    {
        //ciphers initialization 

        SecretKey secretKey = THE_KEY;

        //Decryption cipher
        Cipher dec = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] ivDec = new byte[dec.getBlockSize()];
        IvParameterSpec ivparDec = new IvParameterSpec(ivDec);
        dec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey,ivparDec);

        //Encryption cipher
        Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = new byte[enc.getBlockSize()];
        IvParameterSpec ivpar = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey,ivpar);
    }
    catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Here is the encrypt/decrypt methods :

```
public static String encrypt (String data)
{   
    String encData = null;
    byte [] arr = null;
    try
    {
        arr = enc.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        //convert to base 64
        String base64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(arr);
        encData = base64;
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return encData;
}
public static String decrypt (String data)
{   
    String decData = null;
    byte [] arr = null;
    try
    {
        //convert base64 to bytes[] 
        byte[] base64 = Base64.decodeBase64(data);
        arr = dec.doFinal(base64);
        decData = new String(arr,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return decData;
}
```

How can I improve the performance of this code ?

Comment: How slow is it? Do you have some numbers?

Comment: About 5 microsecond per word

Comment: So about 1 MB per second then. It's not too bad. It also depends on what you're actually measuring. If you would measure only the encryption without file reading/writing of a text file that is at least 50 MB and it would still be as slow, then there is really something wrong with your PC/JVM.

Comment: I did the measuring without calculating the read/write

Comment: First, why are you converting the data to be encrypted to Base64 *before* encrypting it?  Just feed the byte array into your encryption process; it is designed to accept bytes.  You can convert to Base64 if you need to handle the cyphertext as text, not bytes.  Second, how fast is your Base64 conversion?  Try timing just the Base64 conversion without enccryption/decryption.

Comment: @rossum Average of 2 microseconds

Comment: @rossum He is base64-encoding after encryption.

Comment: How big was the data you tested it with? Remember that the JVM takes a bit to warm up, so timing is very tricky with intermediate code like byte code.

Comment: @ArtjomB. 2500 words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should try and *stream* your data or - even better - map your files using `java.nio` use `Cipher.update`. Then you can directly encrypt/decrypt the *binary data*. Reading everything in memory may result in disk trashing if the data doesn't fit in the available RAM, and even out-of-memory errors.

Converting your plaintext to `String` will make things worse, especially since Oracle's Java (before 9) uses 16 bit characters for ASCII internally. Encoding it as base 64 is unneeded if you're going to store it as binary file in the first place. Base 64 adds even more to the memory overhead.

Your runtime makes a lot of difference. The latest Oracle provided runtimes have a lot of performance improvements, so make sure you run the latest *server* VM so you can use things like AES-NI intrinsics.

Comment: I am decrypting the .txt file line by line using BufferedReader, Thats why I need to convert the binary returned by the enc.doFinal method  to base64 in order to read it as string, I also tried using cipher.update but the returned data is not valid unlike doFinal method